# Problems with this Cartesian Product definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

Supposed I do not define ordered pair in the usual Kuratowski way $(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. I left the ordered pair undefined but with the propriety $(x,y) = (x',y') \iff x=x'\text{ and }y=y'$. Then I postulate the axiom:

For every sets $A$, $B$, there exist one unique set $\sf CP$ (Cartesian Product) such that $(x,y)\in\mathsf{CP}\iff x\in A\text{ and }y\in B$.

The remain $\sf ZFC$ axioms unchanged. Can be a contradiction be found with under this conditions?

Comment: Do you require that if $A'\subseteq A$ then $A'\times B\subseteq A\times B$ for all $B$?

Comment: I do not require that but that can be deduced from this Cartesian Product  axiom.

Comment: How? You didn't require anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. What is $(x,y)$?

In the language of set theory there is only a binary relation symbol $\in$, which $x\in y$ is interpreted to mean "$x$ is an element of $y$".

If you added a new function symbol $O(x,y)$ and the axioms that $O(x,y)=O(x',y')$ if and only if $x=x'$ and $y=y'$, then you could argue that by adding the axiom that for every $A$ and $B$ there is a set $\sf CP(A,B)$ which is effectively $A\times B$, you didn't change anything.

But you still need to address something. Now that you have added a new function symbol to your language, you have more formulas. So you need to decide whether or not you want to extend the Replacement schema or not, or other schemata if you have them.

In general, however, this is easily equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC$, since it is in fact a conservative extension. We have a definable $O(x,y)$ function, namely the Kuratowski (or any other) definition of an ordered pair.

But the beauty of set theory is in its simplicity. The fact that a few axioms (and a schema) can do so much with just one binary relation symbol.

Comment: Given two sets x, y then (x,y)  [or as you said  O(x,y)] is a set. Yes, in my language, Replacement is extended with this new symbol. I was afraid of  the regularity axiom that in some way forbidden me state that (x,y) is a set . If I didn't change anything, it is a relief to me. Thanks you very much, but I will wait a confirmation from you.

Comment: Why is "regularity" preventing you from declaring that it is a set? The universe is still going to be made only out of sets. You're just not going to require explicitly that the Kuratowski definition is used.

Comment: I believe that regularity would force me to talk about "atoms" putting my language farther from ZFC than I want.

Comment: I still don't see why. At best, regularity will force you to give an explicit definition of what $(x,y)$ is. But even then, it's not going to do that.